# Finite State Machine: Explain what the following line of code does

Tags: python, dictionary, state-machine

I'm currently trying to understand the [implementation](http://www.python-course.eu/finite_state_machine.php) of finite state machine in Python.

```
while True:
        (newState, cargo) = handler(cargo)  #(this line)
        if newState.upper() in self.endStates:
            print("reached ", newState)
            break 
        else:
            handler = self.handlers[newState.upper()]
```

I cannot understand what *(this line)* does. I suppose that *handler(cargo)* returns the name of the next state corresponding to the value of *cargo*, but *handler* seems unrelated to *handlers* dictionary.

So, can you, please, tell me what this line does, or where can I find more information related to this kind of operation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `handler()` returns a two element tuple; `(newState, cargo) = handler(cargo)` unpacks that tuple into two names...

Comment: few lines above: `try: handler = self.handlers[self.startState]` does that explain what `handler` is?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, know I understand. 'handler' is like a reference to a function in this case. Am I right?

Comment: exactly, the values in the `self.handlers` dict are all functions defined below in the example, like `start_transitions` and `python_state_transitions`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handlers` is a mapping from state names to transition functions.  `handler` is the transition function for the current state.

Initially `handler` is set to the transition function for the start state.  At each iteration of the loop, the current `handler` function is called on the current value of `cargo`.  This function returns the next state and an updated cargo value.  The line you have called out takes these two values and assigns them to `newState` and `cargo`, respectively.  After that the code checks if the new state is an end state.  If it is, the loop terminates.  If not, the value of `handler` is updated to the transition function of the new state and the loop continues.

---

Example of the "tuple assignment" syntax:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 1, 2, 3
... 
>>> a, b, c = foo()  # parentheses on left side of = are optional
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand how this program works.